# Angular 2, Laravel 5.2 and ioredis real time app

Tags: node.js, laravel, angular, redis

I've been searching for almost 10 hours and just found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725071/angular2-laravel-with-real-time-websockets), that hasn't been answered they way it should be though I've tried my best to make it possible. Sorry if it is just dumb question but either I'm not aware or it's not working the way it should be.

So my angular 2 component has something like

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
export class TasklistComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit() {
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.on("test-channel:TasklistModified", function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
 }
}
```

I've configured `socket.js` on my laravel root directory.

```
var app = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var Redis = require("ioredis");
var redis = new Redis({
   scheme: 'localhost',
   port: 6379,          // Redis port
   host: '127.0.0.1'
});

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
   //..
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
   console.log("Message Recieved", channel, message);

   message = JSON.Parse(message);
   io.emit(channel + ":" + message.event, message.payload);
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

And I've the following event class and route on laravel `routes.php`

```
Route::get('event', function() {
   event(new TasklistModified([
        'name' => 'test'
    ]));
});
//Event Class
use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TasklistModified extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;
    public $tasklist;
    public function __construct($tasklist)
    {
        $this->tasklist = $tasklist;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

I've open two browser and tried running,

Angular : localhost:4200

And Laravel

localhost:8000/event

I couldn't get any response when I hit `event` route in laravel.

**Applications Running**

Node: 3000

Laravel: 8000

Angular2: 4200

Your answers will be appreciated a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forget to install Redis on my windows machine. Everything seems fine now. :)
 [Here's how you can install Redis on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows). Try @Dherik answer